To rid windows: which partitions are safe to delete?
Was about to install Ubuntu (want to rid windows, I've never used anything later than windows 7 and never will), and it gave me a choice to delete partitions.
Don't know which are safe to delete though.
Gparted detected the partitions and I haven't done this so wanted to be sure and ask first. Better safe than sorry!


Which version of Ubuntu are you trying to install? Edit your question and add this information. If you are using the Ubuntu 24.04, you should choose "Erase disk and install Ubuntu: Start from scratch on your selected disk." Make sure you have copied all your personal files and data.in an external drive before you do anything.

Yes using Ubuntu 24. Ok that's what I was about to do, erase disk (all the partitions) but am practicing caution. Bought the laptop used, so not worried about losing files, but, my knowledge is limited and want to ensure that deleting all of the partitions wouldn't somehow kill the laptop. Thanks!

Do not manually delete any partition. Let the installer do its job. See the instructions in this quide You will need an ESP also known as EFI Systems Partition to boot the computer.

Will let the installer do the erase as you suggested. Will I really need the EFI after that? The page you linked to has the instructions for EFI under the manual install, which you advised to avoid.  How do I add an EFI? (don't even know what that is!)

You don't need to worry about the EFI if you let the installer erase the whole disk and install Ubuntu. The installer will create the EFI System Partition.

Stick to the safe and sane default settings of the Ubuntu installer.
It will handle deleting the appropriate partitions for you. It will handle adding an appropriate EFI partition (if needed) for you.
Do not try to outwit the installer. Just let the installer do the job that it was created to do.
Do not try to do a fancy or unusual install. For your first install, keep it simple. Stick to the defaults. Make it successful instead of perfect. You can always do a complex reinstall later.

I agree with you. Even for experienced users the default install works in 90% of the time.
